# Adding shared USB key to a Raspberry Pi that is running Pi-Hole

Tags: usb, pi-hole, shared-libraries

I have an original Raspberry Pi running Pi-Hole that is working successfully.
I was wondering whether I could connect a USB key to the R-Pi  to act as shared network storage on my LAN. To get Pi-Hole working as I wanted, I had to add another router to my network which doesn't have any USB ports. I've tried Telnet to access the R-Pi but the service doesn't appear to be running so I'm not sure how to access the Raspberry Pi OS setup.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Had you enabled ssh when you built the pi? If not the simplest way is to put a keyboard / monitor on the pi and run ‘sudo raspi-config` and enable ssh for remote access.  Mac / Linux can use ssh from the terminal, Windows needs to install putty.  Once done you need to understand how to mount the usb and share using NETATALK (MAC) or samba (MAC, Windows, Linux).  I have a 4Tb usb drive hanging off my pi-hole box with no issues

Comment: I didn't enable SSH so can't connect remotely, I'll have a go at using a keyboard over the weekend. Thanks

Comment: SSH now enabled and working, will now look at setting up Samba.   Thank You.